# Get U are U figerprint template on PHP backend from Java

Tags: java, php

I'm currently trying to get fingerprint templates from java, I have already sent the templates over HTTP request but I don't know how to get it on Laravel PHP backend to save them as blob on database, I'm sending templates as ByteArrayInputStream. Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
ByteArrayInputStream[] templatesArray = new ByteArrayInputStream[4];

for(int i=0; i<fingers.size(); i++)
{
    templatesArray[i] = new ByteArrayInputStream(fingers.get(i).getTemplate().serialize());
}
```

Next I send that array over http with Retrofit. I'm getting them as usual on laravel using:

```
$request->input('fingers')
```

Comment: You should try and ask a specific question or at least provide some code. This is really too broad to answer. *What have you tried?*

Comment: I've posted what I've done. After iterate that array on PHP nothings is saved on database.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a POST? Suppose from a practical debugging standpoint I'd suggest starting with a limited script in that PHP apps public/root that simply does a `var_dump($_REQUEST);` If you don't get data there you will need to look at limits in the PHP environment on [`max_post_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size).

If you do get data you should drop the `java` tag, add a `Laravel` tag, and slightly rephrase the question with what you've learned.

Assume it's essentially a file upload. You don't need to base64_encode anything on that Java side do you?